# Strange drawing of Arrowheads in 2D

Tags: graphics, arrowhead

Let's say, I have an array of numbers which define the length of vertical vector.

```
a={2.82345, -1.47024, -8.24342, -18.139, -22.7169, -13.6214, -4.18446, \
-0.0518885, -0.337122, -4.40746, -7.29603, -8.45888, -5.10904, \
1.46547, 12.2129, 19.4917, 14.5857, 7.07756, 3.33114, 1.84374, \
0.292122, -2.01606, -3.22872, -3.94084, -4.42701, -5.71311, -6.23376, \
-4.98916, -3.90659, -3.88277, -4.60968, -4.82429, -10.6043, -24.292, \
-48.1282, -67.7794, -57.9323, -31.2675, -62.2379, -165.641, -363.452, \
-535.344, -454.985, -255.472, -112.982, -26.0016, -3.9861, -4.65554, \
-15.675, -37.0327, -72.5074, -133.949, -212.122, -337.342, -491.234, \
-496.722, -333.76, -192.772, -115.741, -56.1937, -18.2679, 7.05441, \
17.577, 12.1383, 4.71938, 0.225953, -1.45264, -1.57942, -1.09874, \
-0.335794, 0.146251, 0.0609895, -0.380708, 0.638458, 3.42931, 8.8803, \
12.7845, 9.40522, 4.13318, 4.6508, 10.1378, 22.3934, 30.8586, \
22.4923, 10.3494, 3.29678, 0.893481, 5.11216, 18.1977, 37.518, \
56.6805, 61.1289, 40.9371, 18.2457, 5.69767};

st = Sequence[
   ImageSize -> 500,
   PlotRange -> {-550, 550},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {tks, None}},
   AspectRatio -> 0.4];

Graphics[{Thick, Arrowheads[{{.015, 1}}], 
  Table[{
    If[a[[i]] > 0, Red, Blue], 
    Arrow[{{i*10, 0}, {i*10,a[[i]]}}]}, 
    {i, 1, Length@a}]},
 st]
```

[image]

Can somebody explain why the arrowheads of near zero y-values look so ugly? All vectors have to start from the zero height but as one can see some of them start from somewhere else..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem is that the arrow head is longer than the arrow. Instead, we can add the triangles manually (but extending beyond the actual datapoint!):

```
size = {5, 20}
h = Polygon[# size & /@ {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}, {-(1/2), 0}}];
j = Polygon[# size {1, -1} & /@ {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}, {-(1/2), 0}}];
Graphics[{Thick, Arrowheads[{{.01, 1, {h, 0}}}], 
  Table[{If[a[[i]] > 0, Red, Blue], Line[{{i*10, 0}, {i*10, a[[i]]}}],
     Translate[If[a[[i]] > 0, h, j], {i*10, a[[i]]}]}, {i, 1, 
    Length@a}]}, st]
```

[image]